# Map file showing world countries with US State detail for Mapbox and Power BI

Tags: powerbi, mapbox, gis, geojson, shapefile

I am hoping to find any type of map file (geojson, shape file, etc.) that is a world map with countries, but for the United States, it shows the states. So the States can appear like countries for the US, and then all over countries.

Does anyone know if this exists or how I can create it?

This is for use in Mapbox and Power BI.

Answer (score 0):

This [github repository](https://github.com/PublicaMundi/MappingAPI/tree/master/data/geojson) contains both the [world](https://github.com/PublicaMundi/MappingAPI/blob/master/data/geojson/countries.geojson) and the [USA states](https://github.com/PublicaMundi/MappingAPI/blob/master/data/geojson/us-states.json) geojson. You will need to 'join' both datasets using a GIS software like QGIS.